# Search for managed metadata fields that are empty

Tags: managed-metadata, caml

I want to do a caml query for a specific managed metadata field, 'mark', and only returns the items that have an empty/null 'mark' column. How can I do this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `isNull` tag if the field is empty it should be of null value

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <IsNull>
         <FieldRef Name='mark' />
      </IsNull>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: that doesn't work for a managed metadata field

Comment: just gets all of them